# Square Issue with decimal pricing

Tags: api, decimal, square-connect, price

I have added a couple of products in the Square dashboard with decimal price variations. Connect v1 items end point returns wrong pricing.

i added an item with price 55.00 it shows 5500
50.00 shows 5000

This is the response from Square API:
[image: this is the response from Square API]

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The money amount number is in the lowest denomination of the currency and is always an integer. For USD, it's in cents. Here is the more detailed documentation: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#datatype-money

Comment: Thankyou J. Zhao. It was my bad i didn go through the docs and straight away posted.